# How to customize product card on Dolibarr?

Tags: dolibarr

I'm trying to use dolibarr and I'm having some troubles with product's card. I would like to split some informations on the card. For now I have two tables on the card, but I would like to put some informations of the second table in a third one. I also would like to put some other information in another tab. I read the dolibarr documentation and watch some vids on youtube but I didn't found how to do that.

Do someone have any informations about how to do that ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Hello to change the view of product card you need to do some changes in this file in the main folder of dolibarr project you will find product folder in this folder you will find card.php inside this file search for this word " * View " under this line thers is the code of the view of product card.

if you are looking for doing changes it's better to do that in a test project

any question im here ?
good luck